# Notes Client Java UI API

Tags: java, lotus

I found the article about Notes Client Java UI API, that provides possibility to manipulate Lotus Notes UI:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Notes_Client_Java_UI_APIs-v8.5.2

That's great and I want to use it. But I cant understand where I can find the library with this API. Can anyone share the link, where I can download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no links for Notes Client Java UI API. This API is included in Lotus Notes Client distribution. This API is used by Eclipse plugin developers and it cannot be used directly in your database.
**Some helpful links**

0. [Here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Video_Creating_Your_Fist_Eclipse_Plugin_For_Lotus_Notes)<sup>0</sup> you can get some video tutorials for creating Eclipse plugin for Lotus Notes. In Part3 of this tutorials you can find use of API.
1. [Here](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Java%20UI%20API%20Exerciser/releases/9962EFCE130305FC862576A9005890C3)<sup>1</sup> you can get sample plugin and try to use it. This plugin will add an icon to your `SideBar`:
[image]
And add some additional menus to `Document Properties` menu:
[image]

<sup><sup>0</sup> Google or search on youtube for «Creating Your First Eclipse Plugin For Lotus Notes».

<sup>1</sup> Google for «Java UI API Exerciser».</sup>